# I can no longer change any setting in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

*"unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again"*. I'm getting this error and I cannot make any changes in VS Code.

This is what my error looks like:

[image: This is what my error looks like]

What should I do?

Comment: It is because your `settings.json` file is no longed valid json - often just missing a comma between entries.  If you don't see where the problem is copy the whole thing and paste it into an online json linter - they usually do a pretty good job telling you exactly where the issue is.

Comment: @Mark That was really helpful, thanks!